# Outputting a scrollable div when original div is clicked, and automatically scrolling to bottom of div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div where, when you click it, it's suppose to output another scrollable div, and scroll to the bottom of that div. Right now, it's outputting the scrollable div, but it's not scrolling to the bottom of it. What am I doing wrong?

**test1.php**

```
#output {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
}

<div id = "output" onclick = "scrollToBottom()"> Click me </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript"> 
    function scrollToBottom() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test2.php",
            error: function(xhr,status,error){alert(error);},
            success:function(data) {
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
            } //end of success:function(data)
        }); //end of $.ajax

        var objDiv = document.getElementById("messageBox");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;

    } //end of scrollToBottom()
</script>
```

**test2.php**

```
<?php
    echo "
    <style>
        #messageBox {
            border: 3px solid green;
            overflow-y: scroll; 
            height: 400px;
            padding: 1%;
        }
    </style>

    <div id = 'messageBox'>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
"
?>
```

Comment: looks to be working here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMdPay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to scroll to the bottom of the div created by the click. If so, the issue is mostly likely

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("messageBox");
objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
```

is firing before the success function. So try:

```
success:function(data) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = data;
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("messageBox");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
} //end of success:function(data)e
```